# Bootstrap grid with cards

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Check out my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/bzhd01qr/1/

I'm using cards for this layout:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="bs-component">
            <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <blockquote class="card-blockquote">
                        <p>Card 1</p>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

At the moment I have one main with what I have so far. The spacing between each card, both horizontal and vertical. It should all be the same (for example 5px). So that basically means:

1. The space on the outside is fine (margin on left, top and right)
2. The space between for example Card 1 and Card 2 is too much.
3. The space between Card 1 and Card 4 is too big.
4. There is no space at all between Card 3 and Card 7.

The ideal solution is this:

[image]

Any pointers on how to solve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not usually using bootstrap. But i believe what you looking for is Masonry system, which is also available on bootstrap.

Here for you :

**Bootsrap**

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Masonry</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="item col-lg-3">
      <div class="well"> 
        <p>Card 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-6">
        <div class="well"> 
        <p>Card 2</p>
        <p>Card 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-3">
        <div class="well"> 
        <p>Card 3</p>
        <p>Card 3</p>
        <p>Card 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-3">
        <div class="well">
        <p>Card 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-3">
        <div class="well"> 
         <p>Card 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-3">
        <div class="well"> 
        <p>Card 6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-lg-3">
        <div class="well">
        <p>Card 7</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
.row {
  -moz-column-width: 18em;
  -webkit-column-width: 18em;
  column-width: 18em;
  -moz-column-gap: 1em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 1em;
  column-gap: 1em;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .25rem;
  width: 100%;
}
.well {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

Working Fiddle : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anplusdre/jo67qrok/)

Comment: I might be doing something wrong :) Doesn't work for me. What I get to see is this: Local: https://imgur.com/a/Y44Zd - And on your fiddle link it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/8mBvp